# Is there a way to add class to all elements

Tags: javascript, css, addeventlistener

I browsed thru various similar questions, but I found nowhere real help on my problem. There are some Jquery examples, but none of them weren't applicable, since I want to do it by vanilla JavaScript only.

### The Problem

I have rating widget which I want to build like every time I click on "p" element, `eventListener` adds class "good" on all p elements before and on the clicked one, and remove class good on all that are coming after the clicked one.

### My Thoughts

I tried to select all the "p" elements and iterate over them by using a for loop to add class before and on clicked element, and to leave it unchanged or remove after, but somewhere I am doing it wrong, and it adds class only on clicked element not on all previous ones.

### My Code

```
function rating () {
var paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = 0; i < paragraph.length; i++) {
    paragraph[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.target.className='good';
        })
      }
    } 

rating();
```

### Result

Expected result is that every p element before the clicked one, including clicked one should be having class good after click and all the ones that are after the clicked one, should have no classes.

Actual Result: Only clicked element is having class good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Array#forEach , [Element#nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) and [Element#previousElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling)

General logic behind this is to loop through all the previous and next sibling elements. For each element, add or remove the class `.good` until there are no more siblings to handle.

```js
const ps = document.querySelectorAll('p');

ps.forEach(p => {
  p.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let next = this.nextElementSibling;
    let prev = this;
    while(prev !== null){
      prev.classList.add("good");
      prev = prev.previousElementSibling;
    }
    while(next !== null){
      next.classList.remove("good");
      next = next.nextElementSibling;
    }
  })

})
```

```css
p.good {
  background-color: red;
}

p.good::after {
  content: ".good"
}

p {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div id='rating'>
  <p>*</p>
  <p>*</p>
  <p>*</p>
  <p>*</p>
  <p>*</p>
</div>
```

**Alternative:**

Using Array#slice to get the previous and next group of p's.

```js
const ps = document.querySelectorAll('p');

ps.forEach((p,i,list) => {
  p.addEventListener("click", function() {
    
    const arr = [...list];
    const previous = arr.slice(0,i+1);
    const next = arr.slice(i+1);
    
    previous.forEach(pre=>{
       pre.classList.add("good");
    })
    
    next.forEach(nex=>{
        nex.classList.remove("good");
    });
  })

})
```

```css
p.good {
  background-color: red;
}

p.good::after {
  content: ".good"
}

p {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div id='rating'>
  <p>*</p>
  <p>*</p>
  <p>*</p>
  <p>*</p>
  <p>*</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was trying some approach with `forEach` loop but found myself adding classes on all p elements. This solves the problem, and is ES6 too, so @kemicofa, well done mate.

Answer (score 1):

The key ingredient is to use [`Node.compareDocumentPosition()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition) to find out if an element precedes or follows another element:

```js
var paragraphs;

function handleParagraphClick(e) {

  this.classList.add('good');

  paragraphs.forEach((paragraph) => {

    if (paragraph === this) {
      return;
    }

    const bitmask = this.compareDocumentPosition(paragraph);

    if (bitmask & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING) {
      paragraph.classList.remove('good');
    }

    if (bitmask & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING) {
      paragraph.classList.add('good');
    }

  });
}

function setup() {

  paragraphs = [...document.getElementsByTagName('p')];

  paragraphs.forEach((paragraph) => {
    paragraph.addEventListener('click', handleParagraphClick);
  });
}

setup();
```

```css
#rating { display: flex; }
p { font-size: 32px; cursor: default; }
p:hover { background-color: #f0f0f0; }
.good { color: orange; }
```

```html
<div id='rating'>
  <p>*</p>
  <p>*</p>
  <p>*</p>
  <p>*</p>
  <p>*</p>
</div>`
```

Comment: Thank you too @Jeffrey Westerkampf your solution was also a nice one, but I must be honest I never used Node.compareDocumentPosition() before, it is interesting perspective, and also solves my problem.

Comment: Thanks @Srki, it is an interesting perspective indeed. I honestly think kemicofa's answer better fits your case. However my solution would continue to work when you'd, say, wrap each of your p elements within another element.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function setup() {
  var paragraph = document.querySelectorAll("p");
  for (p of paragraph) {
    p.onclick = (event) => {
      let index = Array.from(paragraph).indexOf(event.target);
      [].forEach.call(paragraph, function(el) {
        el.classList.remove("good");
      });
      for (let i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
        paragraph[i].classList.add("good");
      }

    }
  }
}

//Example case

document.body.innerHTML = `
<div id='rating'>
<p>*</p>
<p>*</p>
<p>*</p>
<p>*</p>
<p>*</p>
</div>`;

setup();
```

Comment: Thank you @westdabestdb too your solution was interesting but what I lack there is complete removal of class from p element. Your solution just removes class name and left it with `<p class>` instead of `<p>` when the class good is removed. Which is not completely wrong and works.